# How to separate an array in Perl based on pattern

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a big script but I am stuck on a part. I want to sprit an array based on ".."

From the script I got this:

```
print @coordinates;
gene            complement(872..1288)
```

my desired output:

```
complement   872  1288
```

I tried:

```
   1) my @answer = split(.., @coordinates)
    print("@answer\n");   

   2) my @answer = split /../, @coordinates;

   3) print +(split /\../)[-1],[-2],[-3] while <@coordinates>

   4) foreach my $anwser ( @coordinates )
    {$anwser =~ s/../"\t"/;
    print  $anwser;}

    5) my @answer = split(/../,          "complement(872..1288)"); #to see if the printed array is problematic. 
    which prints:
      )          )          )          )          )          )          )          )          )          
    
    6) my @answer = split /"gene            "/, @coordinates; # I tried to "catch" the entire output's spaces and tabs
    which prints
    0000000000000000000000000000000001000000000100000000
```

But none of them works. Does anyone has any idea how to step over this issue?
Ps, unfortunately, I can't run my script right now on Linux so I used this [website](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php) to run my script. I hope this is not the reason why I didn't get my desired output.

Comment: I think you need to escape the dots like so: `/\.\./`. Otherwise, a dot matches "any character".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did my @answer = split(\.\., @coordinates);  and prints this 0000000000000000000000000000000001000000000100000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
my $RE_COMPLEMENT = qr{(complement)\((\d+)\.\.(\d+)\)}msx;
for my $item (@coordinates) {
    my ($head, $i, $j) = $item =~ $RE_COMPLEMENT;
    if (defined($head) && defined($i) && defined($j)) {
        print("$head\t$i\t$j\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I got exactly what I want.

Comment: Use `qr` when compiling a regex outside of a match, after the binding operator, it's more standard to use `m`.

Comment: You use the /msx there, but I don't think you want any of them. There is no `^` or `$`, so the `/m` has no effect. There is no '.' meta character, so the '/s' has no effect. And, since there's no whitespace, the '/x' has no effect. Not a huge deal, but it's often to exclude extraneous bits in examples to people who are already struggling. Otherwise, they tend to think it's important to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

[split](http://p3rl.org/split) operates on a scalar, not on an array.

```
my $string = 'gene    complement(872..1288)';
my @parts  = split /\.\./, $string;
print $parts[0];  # gene    complement(872
print $parts[1];  # 1288)
```

To get the desired output, you can use a substitution:

```
my $string = 'gene    complement(872..1288)';
$string =~ s/gene +|\)//g;
$string =~ s/\.\./ /;
$string =~ s/\(/ /;
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply.  I typed  my @parts  = split /\.\./, @coordinates;  as I got this array and I got 0000000000000000000000000000000001000000000100000000

Comment: The second argument of split can't be an array.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot once again.

Answer (score 0):

Desired effect can be achieved with

> use of `tr` operator to replace '(.)' => ' '
>
> then splitting data string into element on space
>
> storing only *required* part of array
>
> output elements of array joined with tabulation

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $data = <DATA>;

chomp $data;
$data =~ tr/(.)/ /;

my @elements = (split ' ', $data)[1..3];

say join "\t", @elements;

__DATA__
gene            complement(872..1288)
```

Or as an alternative solution with only substitutions (without splitting data string into array)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $data = <DATA>;

chomp $data;

$data =~ s/gene\s+//;
$data =~ s/\)//;
$data =~ s/[(.]+/\t/g;

say $data;

__DATA__
gene            complement(872..1288)
```

Output

```
complement      872     1288
```

Comment: First of all, thank you once again for your help and for the explanations. I tried both ways and works perfectly.  To be honest the first seems to be better as at the end, you will obtain 3 values at @element and It will be easier to manipulate when you are writing a big script. Just a last thing. At your first solution  I got the following warning **I Use of uninitialized value $elements[2] in join or string at txt.perl line 33, <DATA> line 33**. Is it because I am using an online Perl executor?

Comment: @KGee -- you need see `<DATA>` line 33, what is there? I guess that it could be just an empty line and the code can not split empty line into elements, if no elements then no way to `join` them.

Comment: @ Polar Bear Finally I found it....  **elements = (split ' ', $data)[1..3];** should be **elements = (split ' ', $data)[0..2];**  Thanks again for your time!!!!

Comment: @KGee -- this would be odd. The elements after split should be -- [0]gene,[1]complement,[2]872,[3]1288. If you get assigned elements [0..2] then in such case your data before split do not have 'gene'. I am puzzled how it could happen. Are you mixed code from 1st and 2nd examples? Otherwise I do not see how it could happen.

Comment: @KGee -- Online: [test #1](https://rextester.com/GKYRXQ72290), [test #2](https://onlinegdb.com/S1kvjWuL8).

Comment: Finally I figure it out..... you were 100% correct. Unfortunately, I removed by accident the word "gene" from my final array. So Perl gave me the warning  ** I Use of uninitialized value $elements[2] **  ([0]complement,[1]872,[2]1288)  as I asked to define in 3 "columns".  Sorry about that...